# when I am trying to creating new Angular project and trying to install scss, I am getting error

Tags: angular

When iam trying to creating New project iam getting following Error.

First step:
In Command prompt first I type below command.

> ng new registration-login-angular-material

after it will ask following question,i given YES.

> Would you like to add Angular routing? Yes

after it will ask another question, i given "SCSS".

> ? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? SCSS   [ https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax#scss
>    ]

after iam getting following error in cmd.[image]
**EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\registration-login-angular-material'**

Comment: try to install it in some different location. For example, create 'projects' folder on your desktop, navigate into it and try again

Comment: The `c:/Users` directory is where windows keeps all users home directories. You can't just create random folders in there. First navigate to your current users home directory and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not problem with Angular or Angular CLI. Problem is place where you want to create Angular project `C:\Users` - here you are not allowed to create subfolders. Try to open folder where you are allowed to create subfolders, for example: `C:\Users\<you>`